# Is there some special usage for the type of " std::shared_ptr<void>"? Or is it a misusage of a shared pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I comprehend `std::shared_ptr<int>`,`std::shared_ptr<someClass>` and etc. I understand `void` too. But I am confused when I saw such declaration(i.e. `std::shared_ptr<void>`) recently. Is it a misusage of a shared pointer? Or is there some special usage for it?

Maybe it's to hide the true type of something(which I agree with @user4581301). I mean it's to hide the implementation. I guess I am right. But I have not seen such a code snippet before. So I post this question and hope to confirm my guess.

The code snippet I have seen is something like this(it has been simplified, check cpp.sh/967f4z):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<void> p = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    std::cout << *(std::static_pointer_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>>(p)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you read a good [C++ programming](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book? Did you read the documentation of your C++ compiler, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ? Did you look into some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)? Did you compile with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if you use GCC?

Comment: @about the <void>. I'd reedit it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It compiles. No warning, no error. Check http://cpp.sh/967f4z.

Comment: Indeed, but your code is not very readable. Why not just `auto p = std::make_shared<int>(5);` which is shorter?

Comment: `void` pointers have their uses when you need to hide the true type of something or have to call a C-style  API  that won't do the inheritance and template tricks you're used to in C++. Beyond that, there's not much use for `void*` in C++. I see this as a good way to spread confusion and invite bugs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your advices. I'd follow them.

Comment: Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Consider using [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for your valuable advice. I'd follow it. But please forgive my ignorance, I could not see there is any relationship with the question. Could you please point out it for me?

Comment: @John: Please explain in your question what is your goal and what motivates your question. I cannot guess it. Are you coding some embedded software? Is it life-critical (e.g. inside an aircraft or missile)? Should your C++ code be portable between a [RaspBerryPi](http://raspberrypi.org/) and a plain x86-64 laptop -or web server- computer running Linux?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's written for some embedded software in C++.  It's not life-critical indeed. It would be better if it's portable,  but not necessary. I just think it's strange to use `void` in the `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Maybe it's to hide the true type of something(which I agree with user4581301). I mean it's to hide the implementation. I guess I am right. But I have not seen such a code snippet before. So I posted this question and hope to confirm my guess .